# unable to use styles from local css file

Tags: reactjs, css-loader

I am creating reactjs web app where I am trying to use styles from a local css file. Source code is given for reference.

/src/css/aboutcompany.css

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

/src/AboutCompany.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import style from './css/aboutcompany.css';

class AboutCompany extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p className="style.center"> Company</p>
        <hr/>
        Technologies  is leading  Company  providing end to end software solutions to customers globally. We are specialized in every vertical of industries and deliver quality solutions using latest technologies.
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AboutCompany;
```

webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output: {
      path:'/build/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8081,
      historyApiFallback: true
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
        {
      test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
      use: 'url-loader'
    },
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader'

         },
         {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: 'css-loader'
        }
      ]
   }
}
module.exports = config;
```

As you can see in the AboutCompany.js here `<p className="style.center"> Company</p>` we are trying to use css class center , but it does not work. Can someone tell me where am I wrong.

Comment: tried `className={style.center}`?

Comment: `import './css/aboutcompany.css';` and `className="center"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of **css modules** in development first you need to install `style-loader`:

```
$ npm install style-loader --save-dev
```

then in your configurations pass `modules=true` as an option to `css-loader`

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?modules=true']
}
```

finally in your jsx code you can call your classes like this:

```
<p className={styles.center}/>
```

and you are done.